# g++/gcc not found in PATH. Eclipse. Windows

Tags: c++, eclipse, windows, g++, mingw

I have installed C Compiler, c++ Compiler, MSYS Basic System and MiniGW Dev Tools to C:\MinGW.

I have altered my PATH Variable to ;C:\MinGW\bin;C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin;

Still getting 'Program "g++" not found in PATH.' / 'Program "gcc" not found in PATH.'

Using Windows 10.

Comment: Install Cygwin and gcc

Comment: Aren't they the same thing? https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/howto/EclipseCpp_HowTo.html

Comment: Ah didn't know mingw was similar, i know Cygwin is an easy install you can search by package but idk about mingw

Comment: Your sure you installed the FCC package with it I know for Cygwin you have to manually select the packages

Comment: I think it has something todo with the PATH Variable or some option in Eclipse. But I'm new to both so that's why I asked.

Comment: How would I find out if I have the FCC Package?

Comment: look at C:\mingw\bin for `mingw32-gcc.exe` or similar. copy the file to gcc.exe. Do the same with `mingw32-g++.exe` (copy to g++.exe)

Comment: Have you "g++" already found or can we help?

Answer (score 0):

First, a disclaimer: I have never used Eclipse, (and likely never will).
However, as with all issues of this type, you should first verify that your tools are working correctly, *without* interference from the IDE, by running them directly from the command line.  Thus:--

1) Note that `C:\MinGW\MSYS\1.0\bin should ***not*** be in your path; you should remove it.

2) If you plan to run the tools from a `cmd.exe` shell, you ***do*** need `C:\MinGW\bin` in path; you do not need even this, if your plan is to use the MSYS shell.  It's your choice whether you leave it in, or remove it too.

3) Start the MSYS shell, by running the `C:\MinGW\MSYS\1.0\MSYS.bat` startup script; (any other way of starting it is asking for trouble).

4) Run the `mount` command, to ensure that `C:\MinGW` is mounted on `/mingw`; (if it isn't, run `mount c:/mingw /mingw`, to mount it).

5) Run `gcc --version` and `g++ --version`, to check that the C and C++ compilers are correctly installed; (do likewise for other tools such as `as` and `ld`, because the compilers will also need these).

This should be sufficient to confirm that the compilers are properly installed.  Only *after* you have confirmed this, should you progress to resolving IDE configuration issues. Do please note, if your IDE (Eclipse) depends on MSYS tools, then the IDE itself should be started from a shell invoked by `MSYS.bat`; invoking MSYS tools, without the initialization which this provides, is likely to be unreliable.